# Django error with sites package: "The model Site is already registered in app 'sites'"

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to install the sites package and upon running makemigrations am receiving the error:

> django.contrib.admin.sites.AlreadyRegistered: The model Site is
> already registered in app 'sites'.

This is my admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin

# Register your models here.
from django.apps import apps

models = apps.get_models()

for model in models:
    try:
        admin.site.register(model)
    except admin.sites.AlreadyRegistered:
        pass
```

And here are my installed apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'webpage',
    'django_user_agents',
    'analytical',
    'corsheaders',
    'django.contrib.sites',
]
```

Any idea what might be causing this issue? Please let me know if there is information missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are registering *all* models of *all* apps in your `admin.py`. You seem to be aware of the fact that some model may already be registered and use a try-except block to catch that. But the problem is that *other* packages don't know that you are doing this and obviously **won't** use try-except blocks. You get the error because you successfully register the model `Site` with the admin site but then when `django.contrib.sites` tries to register the same it fails since it is already registered.

One solution may to be order your `INSTALLED_APPS` better and your apps be *last*. Currently you have `django.contrib.sites` listed after many apps (even third party ones):

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites', # Move it here
    'webpage',
    'django_user_agents',
    'analytical',
    'corsheaders',
]
```

Again this might cause errors if some other apps try to register their models. Instead of doing this brute force registering of all models consider registering the models for only *your* app inside it's `admin.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin

# Register your models here.
from django.apps import apps

app_config = apps.get_app_config('your_app_name') # Replace your_app_name it is just a placeholder
models = app_config.get_models()

for model in models:
    try:
        admin.site.register(model)
    except admin.sites.AlreadyRegistered:
        pass
```

Answer (score 1):

Your admin registered the models of sites app before sites app, the best solution is to skip the sites model in your admin so the admin in sites can register its models.