# Already registered models django

Tags: django, django-models

I want to automate registering models in admin.py

here is the code:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.apps import apps


models = apps.get_models()

for model in models:
    try:
        admin.site.register(model)
    except admin.sites.AlreadyRegistered:
        pass
```

Even though i added exception it raises this error

> raise AlreadyRegistered(msg)

> django.contrib.admin.sites.AlreadyRegistered: The model Group is already registered in app 'auth'.

Comment: I fount the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67924302/django-error-with-sites-package-the-model-site-is-already-registered-in-app-s

Comment: Probably you are using an outdated `django` version I have tested your code in Django 4.2.3 and it works. What version  are you using?

Another problem perhaps is that this code runs before other codes that register models. It depends on the order in `INSTALLED_APPS` in django settings.

Answer (score 0):

You are importing this from a proxy object, you can work with:

```
from django.contrib.admin.exceptions import AlreadyRegistered

for model in models:
    try:
        admin.site.register(model)
    except AlreadyRegistered:
        pass
```

Comment: The problem was that
`django.contrib.sites` was after my `core` app in `settings.py` in `INSTALLED_APPS`

Comment: @KhqyOp: you should run this in the `ready` method of the app config, not just somewhere when you *load* the app, only when all apps are ready.

Comment: I got you, thanks for answer!